# ZF2 - Adding Data to the database

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My zend framework 2 project concerns an online restaurant Menu. I have a form to add a new pizza, and when I try to add a new pizza with the help of addPizzaForm.php and add.phtml view, no data added to the table in the database. No error is shown, but no data added as well.

Here are my files, please help me to find out what's wrong with my code.

**PizzaTable.php:**

```
namespace Pizza\Model;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway; 

class PizzaTable{
protected $tableGateway;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway) 
{
    $this->tableGateway=$tableGateway;
}

public function find_all() 
{
//select • FRom Pizza 
    return $this->tableGateway->select();
} 

public function find_by_id($id=0) 
{
$id = (int)$id;
$result=$this->tableGateway->select(array('id'=>$id)); 
$row=$this->tableGateway->current(); 
if ($row)
{
    return $row;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
}

public function save(Pizza $pizza)
{
$data = array ('name'  => $pizza->name, 
            'ingredients'  => $pizza->ingredients,
            'smallprice' =>  $pizza->smallprice,
            'bigprice' =>  $pizza->bigprice,
            'familyprice'  =>  $pizza->familyprice,
            'partyprice'  =>  $pizza->partyprice,
            );
$id = (int) $pizza->id; 
if($id == 0) 
{
    // insert a new record
    $this->tableGateway->insert($data); 
}
else 
{
    // update a new record
    if($this->find_by_id($id)) 
    {
        $this->tableGateway->update($data , array('id'=>$id));
    } 
    else
    {
        throw new \Exception("the pizza with the id = {$id} could not be found in database"); 

    } 
}
}

public function delete($id=0)
{
    $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => (int)$id));
}

}
```

**add.phtml:**

```
<?php

$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('pizza',array('action'=>'add')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('pizza_name')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('ingredients')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('small_price')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('big_price')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('family_price')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('party_price')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('add_pizza')) . "</br>";
echo $this->form()->closeTag();


?>
```

**PizzaController.php:**

```
public function addAction() 
{
    $add_form = new AddPizzaForm(); 
    $request = $this->getRequest(); 
    if($request->isPost()) 
    { 
        $pizza = new Pizza();
        $add_form->setInputFilter($pizza->getInputFilter());
        $add_form->setData($request->getPost()); 

    if($add_form->isValid())
    { 
        $pizza->exchangeArray($add_form->getData()); 
        $this->getPizzaTable()->save($pizza); 
    }

    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('pizza');
}

return array('form' => $add_form); 

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you check the return values of some of these function calls. What does your `$this->tableGateway->insert($data);` return?

Comment: If variable `$pizza` in `PizzaTable->save()` isn't empty problems in the `AddPizzaForm()` or `Pizza()->exchangeArray`.